# How to display page excerpt with readmore link inside an enhanced widget?

Tags: excerpt

I'm trying to display an excerpt of a page inside an enhanced widget.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
$id = 2550;
$post = get_post($id);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_excerpt);
return  $content;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
apply_filters( 'get_the_excerpt', $post->post_excerpt )
```

This will fill the excerpt with the first words from `post_content` when there is no excerpt, because the default filters will take care of that.

Comment: I get the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN in /var/www/localhost/wp-content/plugins/enhanced-text-widget/enhanced-text-widget.php(53): eval()'d code on line 8

Comment: @JamesH That’s a separate syntax error.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to debug this?

Comment: No idea, I don’t know your new source code. Update your question please.